# Why won't my tikzpicture compile?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code will compile in one of my main files, but not the other.  I initiated all the same things involving tikz so I have no idea what the difference is.  Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage {fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb, changepage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{pgnumchapter_nums}
%\usepackage{titlepg}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9pt]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h] %F12
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
\vertex (u1) at (-4, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (-3.5, 0) -- (-2.5, 0);
\vertex (u2) at (-2, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (-0.7,-0.2)--(-4.3,-0.2);
\draw  (-2.5, -.6) node {$k+2$ nodes};
\vertex (u3) at (-1.5, 0) {$v_1$};
\vertex (u4) at (-1, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (-0.5, 0) -- (.5, 0);
\vertex (v1) at (1, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (1.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
\vertex (v2) at (3, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (4.2,-0.2)--(0.7,-0.2);
\draw  (2.5, -.6) node {$k+2$ nodes};
\vertex (v3) at (3.5, 0) {$v_l$};
\vertex (v4) at (4, 0) {};
\vertex (r1) at (5, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (5.5, 0) -- (6.5, 0);
\vertex (rn) at (7, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (7.2,-0.2)--(4.7,-0.2);
\draw  (6, -.6) node {$r$ nodes};


\path 
(u2) edge (u3)
(u3) edge (u4)
(v2) edge (v3)
(v3) edge (v4)
(v4) edge (r1)
; 
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\caption{A minimum failure set of $P_n$}
\label{fig:tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pasting the `undefined control sequence` would be more helpful than saying you got it.  I don't suppose it's saying `\vertex` is undefined?

Comment: I get an error `! LaTeX Error: File `pgnumchapter_nums.sty' not found.` if I ry to run this code.

Comment: If I ignore the missing package errors I get an error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`  please fix your example so that it shows the error you are asking about.

Comment: @Teepeemm Its pretty generic, just says "The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}."

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The begin document line is in there?  I'm not sure why you're getting that error

Comment: @anon no it was not there it has been added by an edit since I commented.

Comment: @anon "Its pretty generic, just says "The compiler is h..." is not the error from tex that is just a useless comment generated by your editor. The error message from Tex will show which command is undefined and the point in the document that the command was located. Look at th log fil or terminal output from tex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how everything unnecessary in the code below is commented out. A minimal example should always be posted.

[image]

You need to use `\node[vertex]` instead of `\vertex`. When you use `\tikzstyle` it does not define a new command like `\newcommand` does. So you can use `vertex` (without the backslash) as a key in other commands, `\node` in this example. But you shouldn't use `\tikzstyle` anyway. Notice the syntax for `\tikzset` in the code below, which is current best practice for defining styles in tikz.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%\usepackage {fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb, changepage}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{pgnumchapter_nums}
%\usepackage{titlepg}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex] (u1) at (-4, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (-3.5, 0) -- (-2.5, 0);
\node[vertex]  (u2) at (-2, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (-0.7,-0.2)--(-4.3,-0.2);
\draw  (-2.5, -.6) node {$k+2$ nodes};
\node[vertex]  (u3) at (-1.5, 0) {$v_1$};
\node[vertex]  (u4) at (-1, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (-0.5, 0) -- (.5, 0);
\node[vertex]  (v1) at (1, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (1.5, 0) -- (2.5, 0);
\node[vertex]  (v2) at (3, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (4.2,-0.2)--(0.7,-0.2);
\draw  (2.5, -.6) node {$k+2$ nodes};
\node[vertex]  (v3) at (3.5, 0) {$v_l$};
\node[vertex]  (v4) at (4, 0) {};
\node[vertex]  (r1) at (5, 0) {};
\draw [dotted, very thick] (5.5, 0) -- (6.5, 0);
\node[vertex]  (rn) at (7, 0) {};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (7.2,-0.2)--(4.7,-0.2);
\draw  (6, -.6) node {$r$ nodes};

\path 
(u2) edge (u3)
(u3) edge (u4)
(v2) edge (v3)
(v3) edge (v4)
(v4) edge (r1)
; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And you should refrain from using `tikzstyle{vertex}=...` but use `tikzset{vertex/.style=...}` instead.

Comment: @SebGlav: Wow! I didn't even notice that in OP's code. Even though I repeated it. I'll change it.

Comment: My comment was intended to OP in the first place, actually ;)